# UPDATE-FROM clause in jOOQ throws an expecption for CTE field

Tags: java, postgresql, sql-update, jooq

I am trying to convert following PostgreSQL query into jOOQ:

```
UPDATE book
SET amount = bat.amount
FROM (
    VALUES (2, 136),(5, 75)
) AS bat(book_id, amount)
WHERE book.book_id = bat.book_id;
```

VALUES inside of FROM-clause are being created from `Map<Long, Integer> bookIdsAmountMap` parameter and I am trying to perform that this way:

```
class BookUtilHelper {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    static Table<Record2<Long, Integer>> batTmp(DSLContext dsl, Map<Long, Integer> bookIdAmountMapUpdated) {
        Row2<Long,Integer> array[] = new Row2[bookIdAmountMapUpdated.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<Long, Integer> pair : bookIdAmountMapUpdated.entrySet()) {
            array[i]=DSL.row(pair.getKey(), pair.getValue());
            i++;
        }
        Table<Record2<Long, Integer>> batTmp = DSL.values(array);
        batTmp.fields("book_id", "amount");         
        return batTmp;
    } 
}
```

Then, I try to also create fields which can be accessed like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10267071/6805866) example

```
Field<Long> bookIdField = DSL.field(DSL.name("bat", "book_id"), Long.class);
Field<Integer> amountField = DSL.field(DSL.name("bat", "amount"), Integer.class);
Table<Record2<Long, Integer>> batTmp = BookUtilHelper.batTmp(dsl, bookIdAmountMapUpdated);
// ctx variable is of type DSLContext
ctx.update(BOOK).set(BOOK.AMOUNT, amountField).from(batTmp.as("bat")) 
 .where(BOOK.BOOK_ID.eq(bookIdField));
```

When I try to update book I get following exception:

> column bat.book_id does not exist

Any advice on how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Note to readers: I've reverted the question's last edit, as @NikolaS has created [a new follow up question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62147745/521799)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have any effect:

```java
batTmp.fields("book_id", "amount");
```

Whereas this only renames the table, not the columns:

```java
batTmp.as("bat")
```

Write this instead:

```java
batTmp.as("bat", "book_id", "amount")
```

Comment: Hi Lukas, thank you for your suggestion but unfortunately it didn't help me solve issue and it caused another exception to be thrown. I've updated my question under EDIT1 part with made changes in code, so please take a look.

Comment: @NikolaS: That's a different, probably unrelated question. This one is about creating derived column lists (`AS table_alias (column_alias, ...)` syntax). The new one is about data types. Would you mind asking a new one? I think that it will be more useful for future visitors if they encounter separate questions. I'll be happy to answer the new one, then.

Comment: @Lukas_Eder: Thank you for pointing that out Lukas, happy to do that. :) Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62147745/6805866) to new created question as you asked.

Comment: Note to readers: With help of Lukas full answer can be found in link mentioned in my comment above. Thank you again Lukas. :)